# How can I clear fields after submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reset the values of the fields after sending the data. Does anyone have a hint how can I clear the fields using javascript?

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Código da Matéria</label>
            <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="codigoMateria"/>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="nome"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-left">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Salvar</button>
```

Comment: forms have a reset method

Answer (score 1):

Like Jaromanda said there is a [reset method for form elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset).

To use it you will need to already have a correct form. Then you’re talking about sending the data. For this you need a `submit` button.
After this to reset your content you can bind the submit event with a function which use the reset method for your form.

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r56nvn51/1/

Comment: You’re welcome, if this answer suits you, you can click on the mark below the answer’s grade. See [help about how to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) here!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the input element with the submit type attribute it will send the data and the reset the page which resets the inputs.

Aside from doing that you will need to add some script.

And you do not need the type in your button element.